# send another Data field to action when i want upload file

Tags: file-upload

i have this controller for uploading file

1. [HttpPost]
2. public JsonResult Upload( HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
3. {
4. //uploadedFile parameter geting seccusfully but i can not get other field such as news about file
5. }

this is my java script for sending file to action

```js
function UploadFile() {

    var form = $('#FormUpload')[0];
    var dataString = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Upload',  
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function () {  
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {  
                //myXhr.upload.onprogress = progressHandlingFunction
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        complete:completeHandler,
        // Form data
        data: dataString,
        //**********
        //i want send another filed with datastring but i can not

        //**********
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

}
```

this is my view code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idGag.jpg)

i want send textarea content with uploaded file to action
tanx